# iterate through all dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare all rows of 2 given dataframes

how can i optimize the following code to dynamically iterate through all columns of the given pandas dataframe?

```python
df1,df2 = pd.read_csv(...)

for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        if row1[0]==row2[0]: i = i+1
        if row1[1]==row2[1]: i = i+1
        if row1[2]==row2[2]: i = i+1
        if row1[3]==row2[3]: i = i+1
        print("# same values: "+str(i))
        i = 0
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `i`? Could you make a reproducible example for your dataframes?

Comment: to access the column names directly, use `df1.columns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested `for` loop suggests that you are comparing all `rows` of the first `DataFrame` to all `rows` of the second `DataFrame`, and count the cases where values in corresponding columns match.

If so, you can fall back on `numpy` broadcasting to `sum` the equal cases for each `row` in `df1` relative to all `rows` in `df2`, and then `sum` these for all `rows` in `df1` to get the total like so:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: np.sum(df2.values == x.values), axis=1)
```

To illustrate, two randomly sampled `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (10, 2)))

   0  1
0  2  4
1  2  3
2  4  1
3  3  3
4  3  3
5  4  4
6  2  4
7  3  4
8  3  4
9  4  1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (10, 2)))

   0  1
0  3  2
1  3  4
2  4  4
3  2  3
4  4  3
5  4  1
6  4  1
7  3  4
8  3  1
9  1  4
```

Get the `sum` of equal values for all `df1` `rows` after comparing each to all `df2` `rows`:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: np.sum(df2.values == x.values), axis=1)

0    5
1    3
2    7
3    6
4    6
5    8
6    5
7    8
8    8
9    7
```

And you could then sum the cases, or do it all in one go:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: np.sum(df2.values == x.values), axis=1).sum()

63
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you need to check whether whole row of one dataframe is equal to another one. You could compare for equality two dataframes then use [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html?highlight=all#pandas.DataFrame.all) method for that with `axis=1` to check rows and then summing the result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 5, 3, 7, 5], 'b': [2, 3, 8, 5, 6]})

In [1531]: df1 == df2
Out[1531]: 
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
3  False   True
4   True   True

In [1532]: (df1 == df2).all(axis=1)
Out[1532]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

In [1533]: (df1 == df2).all(axis=1).sum()
Out[1533]: 2

result = (df1 == df2).all(axis=1).sum()

In [1535]: print("# same values: "+str(result))
# same values: 2
```